# Can the let block be trivially removed from this SICP chapter 3 code without anything changing?

Tags: scheme, sicp

[Chapter 3 of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%25_sec_Temp_386) contains this unusual code block.

```
(define (propagate)
  (if (empty-agenda? the-agenda)
      'done
      (let ((first-item (first-agenda-item the-agenda)))
        (first-item)
        (remove-first-agenda-item! the-agenda)
        (propagate))))
```

To my eye, `first-item` is only used once here, so I don't see the need for the `let`. Is there any particular reason why the following code would not be equivalent?

```
(define (propagate)
  (if (empty-agenda? the-agenda)
      'done
      (begin
        (first-agenda-item the-agenda)
        (remove-first-agenda-item! the-agenda)
        (propagate))))
```

Comment: `first-item` is a procedure and your version doesn't call it like the original does. You need something like `((first-agenda-item the-agenda))` instead.

Comment: @Shawn If I've fundamentally misread the `let` block, then feel free to post that as an answer. The idea of a `let` block that is not doing variable assignment is strange to me.

Comment: It is doing variable binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of your transformation is perfectly fine, but you've done it incorrectly, as Shawn says in a comment.

The simplest example of your error would be to turn code like this:

```
(let ((f something))
  (f)
  x)
```

into

```
(begin
  something
  x)
```

Note that the extra call to `(f)` has been missed here: the original version computes a function *and then calls it*, while the transformation computes a function but throws it away. A more accurate transformation would be:

```
(begin
  (something)
  x)
```

Comment: So, changing `(first-agenda-item the-agenda)` in my question's final code block to `((first-agenda-item the-agenda))` should give code equivalent to the book's?

Comment: Yes, that is what you're meant to understand from this example.

Answer (score 1):

> *"The idea of a `let` block that is not doing variable assignment is strange to me."*

but it does variable initialization, and variable reference. It could be have been written as

```
(define (propagate)
  (if (empty-agenda? the-agenda)
      'done
      (let ((first-item #f))
        (set! first-item (first-agenda-item the-agenda))
        (first-item)
        (remove-first-agenda-item! the-agenda)
        (propagate))))
```

and what you've written is equivalent to

```
(define (propagate)
  (if (empty-agenda? the-agenda)
      'done
      (let ((first-item #f))
        (set! first-item (first-agenda-item the-agenda))
         first-item                              ; NB! _No_ _Parens_
        (remove-first-agenda-item! the-agenda)
        (propagate))))
```

Your line `(first-agenda-item the-agenda)` *returns* the first value in `the-agenda` but does not use it -- doesn't do anything with it.

But the original `(first-item)` refers to that value by name, `first-item`, and *uses* it i.e. calls that value as a function with no arguments.

Following the principle of substituting equals for equals, in a *pure* code (i.e. such that deals only with *values*, and not any *places* in computer memory), we replace the *name* in the pure subset of the code

```
                            ; impure: deals with a named place in computer memory
        (set! first-item (first-agenda-item the-agenda) )
                            ; pure: refers to a value by the name it was given
        (     first-item                                )
```

with its value

```
        (                (first-agenda-item the-agenda) )
```